# jQuery removing random text

Tags: jquery

I've got this piece of text to remove from meta property tag:

> ::cck::2446::/cck::::introtext::

problem is that numbers get randomized each time

I'd go with something like this, replacing numbers with ? or *

```
 $('meta[property="og:description"]').html($('meta[property="og:description"]')
                          .html()
                          .replace('::cck::2446::/cck::::introtext::', ''))
```

can it be done ?

Comment: You can use regex with `replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex pattern with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with a callback to reduce the code.

```
$('meta[property="og:description"]').html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/::cck::\d+::\/cck::::introtext::/, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if only the numbers change, then your data is easily regular enough for a very simple regex replace: (use the known start `::cck` and end sequences `introtext::`, and you can then *ignore* the entire inside of the string, including those changing numbers:

```
$('meta[property="og:description"]')
    .html($('meta[property="og:description"]').html()
    .replace('::cck.*?introtext::', ''))
```